# XML : minify my xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Hi i want to minify my xml,

say it is of 100 kbs so i want to minify it and as much lesser as much i can but don't want to compress zip it. i tried making it in one line but it is not giving it much difference but 10 percent(approx.)
and it will be great if i can do it using xslt but i don't want to use java or c# or any other programming language.
i hope i am making myself clear, but if still have doubts then comment below.

Thanks

P.S. i am using Eclipse IDE for all the code writing

Comment: Does the XML use namespaces? If so, you could try to use shorter namespace prefixes.

Comment: yes it does....and i cant remove them or can use any other namespaces or shorten them

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by minifying (as opposed to compressing). Removing whitespace and getting a 10% reduction is probably quite close to the limit.

Comment: As you can see from the existing comments, it is unclear to most people, what you want to achieve given that you reject most of the ways proposed as not being suitable. I suggest that you enhance your question and paste an extract of an exemplary XML output which you want to minify. Any maybe even an example how you imagine the XML to look after "minification". Maybe this helps in getting better answers.

Comment: @mzjn : i want much lesser size......

Comment: @StefanWinkler : i am really sorry for all the inconvenience but i cant post the code....and cant even the example, as my xml consists of 3097 lines of code so making an example of that...i mean the way it looks is a very difficult task......and what i want my so generated xml should be well formed and no loss of data that's it.....rest minification is acceptable in any way and also the format should be xml only and zip or any other.....m really sorry for all the inconvenience

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to reduce the size of your XML files.

- For example, a properly chosen encoding. In UTF-32 every character in your file will occupy 4 bytes is a lot. It is better to take UTF-8 - then all special characters, like as: `<>";'=` will occupy one byte. But in some situations there will be a lot of characters, that is in UTF-8 will occupy to 3-6 bytes. While the same characters in UTF-16 will occupy 2 bytes. So you should choose the encoding most appropriate for your data.
- Use attributes instead of elements wherever possible. Compare the length of the resulting strings:

  ```
  <person><firstname>John</firstname><lastname>Smit</lastname></person>
  <person firstname="John" lastname="Smit"/>
  ```
- Use short namespace prefixes, instead of a long prefixes. For the most frequently used data use a namespace by default, no prefix. See:

  ```
  <longprefix:person xmlns:longprefix="www.example.com">
      <longprefix:firstname>John</longprefix:firstname>
      <longprefix:lastname>Smit</longprefix:lastname>
  </longprefix:person>

  <p:person xmlns:p="www.example.com">
      <p:firstname>John</p:firstname>
      <p:lastname>Smit</p:lastname>
  </p:person>
  ```

  Please note that namespaces are the same, thus for parser they are identical.
- Sometimes the XML schema or DTD is stored in a XML file with the data. If you have a lot of similar files, the schema is stored in each of them is the extra overhead. You can make a schema in a separate file.
- You can store the data in xml files with no default values. These values can be added automatically when reading. For example

  ```
  <person pet="dog">
      <name>John</name>
  </person>

  <person>
      <name>Mary</name>
  </person>
  ```

  Do you see Mary's pet? But it there! It's a cat by default.

  ```
  <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="person">
      <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:sequence>
          <xs:attribute name="pet" type="xs:string" default="cat" />
      </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  ```
- You should remove all comments from an XML file. A description of the file format can be stored separately.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. Feel free to edit the post. You can write your own answer based on my, rewrite it in proper language.

Comment: my xml is very dynamic...i know there is nothing like very dynamic but still it is. it gets generated by the server on its own so there is nothing that can be set as default. it has only one namespace and that too a very short one...used agian and again. the elements that can be added as attribute i have already transformed my xml in that way. the schema and dtd part i am not getting.....how is that related to minification

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand "I want to minify it but I don't want to compress it". What is the difference between minifying and compressing? If the difference is that you want the compressed form to be XML that retains all the structure and content of the original, then you're out of luck: there's very little redundancy you can get rid of while still keeping the document logically equivalent well-formed XML.

Are you sure there is no scope for a semantic reduction, that is, eliminating the parts of the document that are of no interest to the recipient?

Comment: No, when i am saying that i want to minify it but not compress it, that means i  want to minify the file but still keep it in the same format(as in my case XML) and not want it compress it as zip file.

No, sorry to say that but there is no scope for semantic reduction too

Answer (score 0):

Also consider using one of the many great XML minification tools and / or libraries online. They will, without any additional manual effort from your side, reduce the structure of your XML to a minimum! Note that XML minifiying tools are only able to do so much, as they will *never* attempt to semantically change the structure of your document. Depending on the tool used however, they will reduce whitespace both between tags and attributes, remove comments and even get rid of unused and minify used namespaces. In case you are using NodeJS I may recommend my [minify-xml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minify-xml) package, which will do all the above. You can also access an online version of my library at https://minify-x.ml/.